# Get row, or nearest row above and below a value

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| data  | stuff |
+-------+-------+
| 0.90  |   a   |
| 0.95  |   b   |
| 0.98  |   c   |
| 0.99  |   d   |
| 1.00  |   e   |
| 1.01  |   f   |
| 1.02  |   g   |
+-------+-------+
```

I need the rows that most closely 'surround' (above and below) a given number. For example, if the user inputs 0.96 I need these 2 rows:

```
| 0.95  |   b   |
| 0.98  |   c   |
```

If there is an exact match, I just need that single row. For example, if the user inputs 1 I need this row:

```
| 1.00  |   e   |
```

What MySQL query would return just these specific rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `UNION DISTINCT` with two sub-queries:

```
(select * from `table` where data <= 0.96 order by data desc limit 1)
UNION DISTINCT
(select * from `table` where data >= 0.96 order by data asc limit 1)
```

Comment: How to write the same query in sql server??